# Why does not see the array in the same class?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to write a polynomial class,each polynomial consist of multi poly which I have implemented it with an array, like this code:

```
class polynomial {

private:
    int count;

public: 
    polynomial() {
        count = 0;
        Term terms[10];
    }

    void create(int c) {
        terms[count].coef = c;
    }
};

class Term {

public:
    double coef;
    int expo;
};
```

I have a problem in create method,It does not know terms array and does not access Term object properties. why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// First declare a class that will be referenced
class Term {

public:
    double coef;
    int expo;
};

class polynomial {

private:
    int count;
    // terms should be a class member not a local of constructor
    Term terms[10];

public: 
    polynomial() {
        count = 0;
        // If you declare terms array here 
        // it will be destroy after returns from constructor 
        // Term terms[10];
    }

    void create(int c) {
        terms[count].coef = c;
    }
};
```

If polynomial declaration before Term declaration is requirement for your then **forward declaration** can be used as:

```
class Term;

class polynomial { ... };
class Term { // Real declaration here };
```

But it is not revoke your wrong `terms` definition in the constructor instead of class member.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a class before you use it. So swap the Term and polynomial classes and it should compile just fine. See the examples below :

```
int main(){
    Foo foos[10];
}

class Foo {
};
// In function 'int main()':
// error: 'Foo' was not declared in this scope
```

---

```
class Foo {
};

int main(){
    Foo foos[10];
}
// compiles fine
```

Answer (score 1):

Explore the "forward declaration" methodology. You need to put a forward declaration before you can use Term class in your method. This is just because when you are compiling the Polynomial class compiler does not knows what is Term, when you forward declare it compiler moves ahead in expectation that it will get the definition of Term later on.

```
class Term;

class Polynomial{
..
..
};

class Term{
..
..
};
```

or the other way round declare the class Term before Polynomial class altogether.